# How do I link PayPay Standard on Website to PayPal Account?

Tags: asp-classic

I have Cube Cart V5 installed and have activated PayPal Standard as payment method. On a test sale, the PayPal screen comes up and asks 1) Login to your PayPal Account, 2) Use your credit card. How do I link this to my PayPal account so that purchases are registered to my PayPal account?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Cube Cart but in the most basic way as a paypal merchant you are issued a merchant username and password that represents you and in your management tools for your cart you can cut and paste those values in there that will take care of transactions.

When a payment is initialized it is normally passes values through a URL string.  Your merchant information will be in that string so it can match up to an account to receive money.

Paypal has integration documentation, but the people that support the Cart should be able to help you more efficiently.  See if they have a forum if you don't get direct support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. Paypal works this way, by connecting you directly to paypal and allowing you to sign in and make your payment on their website.  When your customer makes a payment, the money goes into your paypal account which you entered into cube during the setup process.

If you prefer to use paypal's api key, you can learn more about it at this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECAPICredentials/